# Installing FTDI drivers programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, driver, ftdi, wixsharp

So I have a WixSharp installer which is able to run *.exe* driver installers. The problem is that the FTDI driver is a folder named *WIN10_30bit+64bit* which contains following files and folders:
[FTDI files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/modmP.png)

In device manager, if there is a connected device that requires that driver, I can right click the device, click ,,Update drivers" and assign the whole folder as a driver to it. This action would install the driver.

Is there a way to assign that folder as a driver to the system programmatically in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There also exists an installer as executable which you can download from ftdi [website](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm). But it is hidden in the *Comments* section. The screen below shows as red box where to download.

[image]

The executable should be usable for the WixSharp installer.

Comment: I didn't realise that there was an executable installer! It works great, thank you.

Comment: No problem. I just wonder because under win10 (when you have internet connection) the ftdi drivers are usually installed automatically by the OS when you plug in such device. But in offline scenarios it makes sense to add them to installer.

Comment: I was surprised when I received a bug where clients app didn't see any connected devices although I didn't have to deal with anything by myself. It got me in a bit tricky situation and took me a while to find out what was going on. Atleast it made me realise that there is not online world everywhere and everytime :D